# Sikuli screen.wait not working

Tags: java, eclipse, sikuli

I'm using sikuli in Java, current IDE is eclipse oxygen

this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
      <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

my code like this

```
    @Test(description = "spin test")
    public void spinLongPeriod() throws Exception {
        int wait_time, last = 5000;

        caseReq.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                new Pattern("src/test/resources/spin.png"),
                new Pattern("src/test/resources/spin-stop.png"),
                new Pattern("src/test/resources/spin-disabled.png"),
                new Pattern("src/test/resources/good-luck.png"),
                new Pattern("src/test/resources/spin-auto.png")
                ));

        screen.wait(caseReq.get(0), 10);
        while (last >= 0) {
            screen.click(caseReq.get(0));
            screen.click(caseReq.get(1));
            wait_time = 60;
            screen.wait(caseReq.get(0), wait_time);
//          while (wait_time >= 0) {
//              Thread.sleep(1000);
//              wait_time -= 1000;
//              if (screen.exists(caseReq.get(0)) != null) {
//                  break;
//              }
//          }
            --last;
        }
    }
```

I abandoned the sikuli Screen.wait method once because it failed

By using the "while + Thread.sleep" solution for a while

But not this time, error message came out

```
FindFailed: can not find P(src/test/resources/spin-stop.png) S: 0.7 in S(0)[0,0 1920x1080]
```

I'd sought the solution from Internet for a long time...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I use next method

```
private boolean exists(Pattern img, int sec) {
        try {
            window.wait(img, sec);
            return true;
        } catch (FindFailed exeption) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

And it works well. If some image can't be found, try to adjust it by .similar((float)0.5);